# QListWidgetItem - adjust width and height to content

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qlabel, qlistwidgetitem

I have got a `QListWidgetItem`, which has a `QWidget` and some `QLabels`. The height of the labels (`imageLabel`, `titleLabel` and `descriptionLabel`) varies depending on the text length. So does the height of the QWidget, which leds to different sizes in `QListWidgetItem`. So far the parameters for `setSizeHint` are static:

```
QListWidgetItem* listWidgetItem = new QListWidgetItem();
listWidgetItem->setFlags(Qt::ItemIsSelectable | Qt::ItemIsEnabled);
listWidgetItem->setSizeHint(200, 180));

QWidget* widget = new QWidget();

QVBoxLayout* rootLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
rootLayout->setAlignment(Qt::AlignTop);

QHBoxLayout* contentLayout = new QHBoxLayout();
contentLayout->setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft);

QLabel* imageLabel = new QLabel();
imageLabel->setPixmap(pixmap);

contentLayout->addWidget(imageLabel, 0, Qt::AlignTop);

QVBoxLayout* informationLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
informationLayout->setAlignment(Qt::AlignTop);

QLabel* titleLabel = new QLabel("<b>" + title  + "</b>");
titleLabel->setWordWrap(true);
informationLayout->addWidget(titleLabel);

QLabel* descriptionLabel = new QLabel(description);
descriptionLabel->setWordWrap(true);
informationLayout->addWidget(descriptionLabel);

QLabel* dateLabel = new QLabel(date.toString());
informationLayout->addWidget(dateLabel);

contentLayout->addLayout(informationLayout);

rootLayout->addLayout(contentLayout);

QHBoxLayout* buttonLayout = new QHBoxLayout();
QPushButton* buttonOne = new QPushButton(tr("Button 1"));
QObject::connect(buttonOne, SIGNAL(clicked()), mButtonOneSignalMapper, SLOT(map()));
mButtonOneSignalMapper->setMapping(buttonOne, index);
buttonLayout->addWidget(buttonOne);

QPushButton* buttonTwo = new QPushButton(tr("Button 2"));
QObject::connect(buttonTwo, SIGNAL(clicked()), mButtonTwoSignalMapper, SLOT(map()));
mButtonTwoSignalMapper->setMapping(buttonTwo, index);
buttonLayout->addWidget(buttonTwo);

rootLayout->addLayout(buttonLayout);

widget->setLayout(rootLayout);

mListWidget->addItem(listWidgetItem);
mListWidget->setItemWidget(listWidgetItem, widget);
```

Is there any way to properly set the `sizeHint` regarding the width and height of the displayed content used in the `QLabels` of the `QWidget`?

For instance the first `QListWidgetItem` may have a `descriptionLabel` with a text length of 300 characters and the second `QListWidgetItem` may have a `descriptionLabel` with a text length of 1000 characters. So far both `QListWidgetItems` will have the same size (200px width and 180px height). While it may fit on the first `QListWidgetItem`, because it has only 300 characters, it may not fit on the second `QListWidgetItem`, because of the 1000 characters. Therefore I would like to somehow dynamically adjust the size of the `QListWidgetItem` regarding the needed space (first one will need less than the second one).

Comment: What is it exactly that you're trying to achieve? Are you aware that setting the `sizeHint` on a `QListWidgetItem` is a no-op until you configure the view's header to actually use said size hint? You'd need to post a self-contained example that demonstrates the problem, with an explanation of what you expect. So far I don't know what other code is missing, and what you really want to happen. Your question is worded as if you wished all the item sizes to be the same (you complain that they are different).

Comment: @KubaOber I have edited my question. I wish to have different sizes on the `QListWidgetItems`.

Comment: Try setting different size hints on a two or three items manually and see if that has any effect. Then you'll know whether you need to do other things first.

Comment: @KubaOber of course it does affect if I for instance use `listWidgetItem->setSizeHint(200, index % 2 == 0 ? 180 : 360));` I just don't know how much height / width each QLabel need for displaying its content.

Comment: Good, because this doesn't happen by default :)

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, you won't be able to get a correct bounding rect for the label, unless you know it's future width, so that you can calculate the number of lines required to display the content. And you won't get the width before the layout with the other widgets is calculated.

An alternate approach might be to use an item delegate. Its sizeHint method has an option parameter with a preliminary rect, from which you can use the width and calculate the height with font metrics.

Concerning your other widgets, you could switch to a QTableWidget and put them in other columns..

The following code is not a working example .. just some clues to get you started..

```
class ItemDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
public:

    void paint ( QPainter * painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem & option, const QModelIndex & index ) const
    {
        painter->save();

        QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter,option,index);

        QString title = index.data(Qt::UserRole).toString();
        QFont f = option.font;
        painter->setFont(f);
        QFontMetrics fm(f);

        QRect r = option.rect;
        // r = r.adjusted(0, fm.lineSpacing(), 0, 0);
        painter->drawText(r.left(), r.top(), r.width(), r.height(), Qt::AlignTop|Qt::AlignLeft|Qt::TextWordWrap, title, &r);

        painter->restore();
    }

    QSize sizeHint ( const QStyleOptionViewItem & option, const QModelIndex & index ) const
    {
        QFont f = option.font;
        QRect r = option.rect;
        QFontMetrics fm(f);
        QString title = index.data(Qt::UserRole).toString();
        QRect br = fm.boundingRect(r,Qt::AlignTop|Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::TextWordWrap,title);
        return QSize(option.rect.width(),br.height());
    }
};
```

Hope it helps,

Johannes